# Not getting response of a webservice in android code

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, web-services

I am working on an application in that i have developed ios code for making a webservice call and it is giving me response successfully,The same webservice call when i am trying to call in android it is not working it is not giving me response,I am posting my both code,Can anybody help me to figure it?

**ios code**

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",k_SERVER_BASE_ADDRESS,service_name]];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    // 2
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",k_CONTENT_TYPE] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // 3
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",k_USER_NAME] forKey:@"APIUserName"];
    [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",k_PASSWORD] forKey:@"Password"];

    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data_prm = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                       options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data_prm encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    if (!error) {
        // 4
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                   fromData:data_prm completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                                                       // Handle response here..

                                                                       NSLog(@"this is data : %@",data);
```

**Android Code**

```
public class GETCONTESTANTS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    StringEntity se;
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        // stateList.clear();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants");
          String json = "";
          try {
          // 3. build jsonObject
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
          jsonObject.accumulate("APIUserName", "AFBK8@DL4EJMd6");
          jsonObject.accumulate("country","8GB4HE1C-EFSD-4L17-VY2D-A27OC8C52F6M");
                   // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
          json = jsonObject.toString();

          // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
          // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

          // 5. set json to StringEntity


            se = new StringEntity(json);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          // 6. set httpPost Entity
          httpPost.setEntity(se);

          // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
          httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        try {

             HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

             // 9. receive response as inputStream
             inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

In above codes "iOS code" is working fine and "android code" is not working. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Debug your code and try to post logcat output

Comment: are you getting any error/exceptions?

Comment: what exactly you getting as error ?

Comment: instead of using asyncTask you you can use Retrofit it's the best HTTP client Library and it's very simple to use . check this link :
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I guess HttpClient is deprecated. Use HTTPURLConnection in an AsyncTask or Retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet of code may be helpful

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jobj = null;
    static String json = "";
    String url="http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants";

    public JSONParser(){

    }


   public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url){

    JSONObject jo = null;
    jo = new JSONObject();

    try {
         jo.accumulate("APIUserName", "AFBK8@DL4EJMd6");
      jo.accumulate("country","8GB4HE1C-EFSD-4L17-VY2D-A27OC8C52F6M");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject job=new JSONObject();
    try {
        job.accumulate("aloha", jo);
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("url", job.toString());
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.url);
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(job.toString(), "UTF-    8"));

           //               httppost.toString();
        //              Log.e("url", httppost.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            is = httpentity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");   

                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("url", json);
                try {
                    jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return jobj;

     }
```

Comment: I tried with RestAPI-> response like Invalid password

Comment: Have you checked it in a tool or else?and how to call this class?

Comment: Try this-->JSONParser object=new JSONParser (); object.makeHttpRequest("http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants");

Comment: Did you got solution?

Comment: Sreekanth - "remove" country and  replace it with "Password",can u help me how to test it?

Comment: did you got solution?